# How can I convert a control that is already bound to multibinding

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding

Let's say I have a FrameworkElement that is already bound to a converter in the XAML. Programmatically, I wish to append a binding to the existing binding at runtime - for instance in the control's loaded event, effectively making it a multibinding.

How does one go about acquiring the existing binding on (for example) the Visibility property.

Comment: You may try [BindingOperations.GetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbinding.aspx) to get an existing binding.

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel with a single `bool` property to bind the `Visibility` to and manipulate that property according to the logic defined there.

Comment: @HighCore - I don't have control over how most of the application is developed unfortunately and most of it doesn't use the MVVM approach sadly :( - I'd love it to, but it'll be far too much effort to re-engineer it that way. The only viable approach is to modify my base controls to append to existing bindings in each control's loaded event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
var oldBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(element, UIElement.VisibilityProperty);

var newBinding = new MultiBinding { Converter = ... };

var firstBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = oldBinding.Path,
    Source = oldBinding.Source // or RelativeSource or ElementName
};

var secondBinding = new Binding
{
    ...
};

newBinding.Bindings.Add(firstBinding);
newBinding.Bindings.Add(secondBinding);

BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, newBinding);
```